# Element relative height in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have seen that the *width* of an element can be set to a fraction of the screen width by using a relative layout (code below showing ONLY the relevant properties):

```
<LinearLayout>
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".40" />
  </imageView>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android_layout_weight=".60" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But ... apparently this same trick can NOT be done for assigning proportional **height** of an element.  Eclipse complains if I attempt to set a layout_height of 0dp.   What should I do if I want an image with a caption, where the image takes up 40% of the screen height and the caption below gets 60% ?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed assign weights for both horizontal and vertical orientations of a LinearLayout.

Horizontal orientation example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".40" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".60" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Vertical orientation example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".40" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".60" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As an aside, it's useful to know that you don't have to specify floating point numbers for the weights.  Android will simply sum up all of the weights and then divide by the total to get the percentage for each.  So using 4 and 6 respectively for the layout_weights would have worked just as well.

Comment: Aha!  The key thing is the property in the LinearLayout, android:orientation="vertical".  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:orientation="vertical" to your layout and then set layout_height=0dp and weight to wanted values.

So:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <ImageView
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight=".40" />
   </imageView>
   <TextView
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android_layout_weight=".60" />
</LinearLayout>
```